# How to perform sorting on Associated Data in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have successfully done Sorting Table with the help of **[RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)**. Now in my index page I have `Store` column which is associated with `Campaign` Module. I tried a lot to perform sorting(asc/desc) order on that column but not performed.

Here is Few Codes:

Model : **campaign.rb**

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store # association with stores table
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :location
  ......
  ......
end
```

Model : **store.rb**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  ........
end
```

Controller : **campaigns_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @campaigns = Campaign.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_campaign
      @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
    end

    # methods for sorting
    def sort_column
      Campaign.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : 'id'
    end

    def sort_direction
      %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : 'asc'
    end
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
 def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end
```

View **index.html.haml**

```
%table
      %tr
        %th Sr. No.
        %th Store  # wanted to sort this column
        %th
          = sortable 'title','Title' # successfully sorted
- @campaigns.each do |campaign|
      %tr
         %td = campaign.title
         %td = (campaign.store.name rescue '')
```

Additional required information will be provided. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: to sort on the association you would need to `join` it into the query appropriately. Right now you are retrieving all the attributes for `Campaign` but when you call `campaign.store` it actually runs a second query for that information that looks like `SELECT * FROM stores where store.id = X LIMIT 1`. Something like `Campaign.joins(:store)` or `Campaign.includes(:store)` woudl work better for this. not sure how well it will work with your method though because the sort_column would be `stores.name`.

Comment: Sorry not understood.. instead of = (campaign.store.name rescue '') should I write = (campaign.includes(:store) rescue '') ?? it might through an error...as I just wanted to show store names

Comment: Sorry I meant in your Controller. You are not querying `Store` at all so it cannot sort on a column not included in the query. your index is running `SELECT * FROM campaigns ORDER BY [your sort conditions]` if you add a `join` clause it will read more like `SELECT campaigns.*,stores.* FROM campaign INNER JOIN stores ON campaigns.store_id = stores.id ORDER BY [your sort conditions]` as you can see in the second one sorting stores would be possible but the first one has no reference to stores at all and thus cannot sort on them.

Comment: undefined method `stores' :(

Comment: yes that's because a campaign only has 1 store so it would be `Campaign.joins(:store).order(...)` no "s". The plural is for `has_many` relationships such as `Store.joins(:campaigns)`

Comment: can you please post the answer with controller code as well as view's code for that particular..?? If it works then I appreciate to accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciated and thank full to **[engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky)** for his guidance, help and his precious time for this issue. Now I have found another and easiest way for sorting by using `sorted gem` from **[here](https://github.com/mynameisrufus/sorted)**

no need of too much code.. for associated data I have done..

```
def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.joins(:store, :location).sorted(params[:sort], "title,stores.name,locations.name ASC:DESC?ASC")
end
```

and in **index.html.haml**

```
%th
  = link_to_sorted "Store", 'stores.name'
%th
  = link_to_sorted "Location", 'locations.name'
```

It works perfectly... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt because I am not certain how it will work with your sortable method and I am not great at `haml`

```
def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.joins(:store, :category).select(columns.values.join(",")).order([sort_column,sort_direction].join(" "))
end

def columns
 {"campaigns.id" => "campaigns.id",
  "campaigns.title" => "campaigns.title",
  "categories.name" => "categories.name as category_name",
  "stores.name" => "stores.name as store_name"}
end

def sort_column
  columns.keys.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : 'campaigns.id'
end
```

in view

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Sr. No.
    %th 
      = sortable 'stores.name', 'Store'
    %th
      = sortable 'campaigns.title','Title' # successfully sorted
    %th
      = sortable 'categories.name', 'Category'
- @campaigns.each do |campaign|
  %tr
     %td = campaign.id
     %td = (campaign.store_name rescue '')
     %td = campaign.title
     %td = campaign.category_name
```

I hope this helps since you asked me to post an answer although my comments were meant to be more directionally informative than answer specific.

Comment: Thanks for your response... But it doesn't work... For more detail I post the answer as Question is being too long

Comment: For easy understanding please check the answer posted by me. Hope it help you.

Comment: @Gagan what do you mean doesn't work. Does it throw an error? Like I said I tried to modify your sort code to make this work because you want to sort on a column not in `Campaign` so I have to specify what the columns were. Also select queries will run faster and avoid the n+1 that you are currently experiencing.

Comment: actually it throw an error bcz another model's data are also associated and this only fetch store's data....my mistake... plz check now my updated answer with SQL...I appreciate for your this answer..+1